# (F# RProvider) mean giving a weird result - in some cases

Tags: r, f#, interop, type-providers

I am starting to use the RProvider. For starters, I have just tried to evaluate functions in different ways. It seems I have already run into problems (perhaps a problem with my understanding of how the RProvider works). I have run the same function in four different ways, which I thought to be equivalent. However, the four example provides me with two different results.

```
R.sapply(R.c(1,2,3,4,5), R.eval(R.parse(text="mean"))).GetValue<float[]>() 
// val it : float [] = [|1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 4.0; 5.0|]
R.sapply(R.c(1,2,3,4,5),"mean").GetValue<float[]>() 
// val it : float [] = [|1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 4.0; 5.0|]
R.mean(R.c(1,2,3,4,5)).GetValue<float[]>() 
// val it : float [] = [|3.0|]
R.eval(R.parse(text="mean(c(1,2,3,4,5))")).GetValue<float[]>() 
// val it : float [] = [|3.0|]
```

Can anyone tell me why this is? My own guess is that `R.sapply` applies the given function element-wise. But how do I get around this?

Comment: Start by reading R-tutorials would be my advice.

Comment: Don't use `sapply()` if you want to apply the funcion element-wise?

Comment: You are right, `sapply` allows to apply a function to each element of a vector, list, or data frame. So in your case, it applies the function `mean` to each coefficients of your vector. What do you mean by "get around this"?

Comment: I mean, how do I apply the function to the vector (or whatever the R-type is called), instead of to each element in the vector?

Comment: Isn't this your last case?

Comment: and the second last case???

Comment: That is the two last cases - yes. But I'd like to call it in one of the first two ways, the reason being that I might want to call some other non-trivial function, defined in a script (which I would have then loaded prior to calling it).

Comment: Since I can't understand what you're asking at all, I'll provide the only advise I can: you should rule out options 1 and 4 entirely and never consider them again. You should (almost) never be executing R code via `eval(parse())`.

Comment: I **think** that you're looking for whatever the analogue of R's `do.call` is in RProvider (btw, since f# is fairly unfamiliar to most of the r community it might have been nice to provide a link: http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/

Comment: i.e. you want to mimic this R call: `do.call("mean",list(c(1,2,3,4,5))`

Comment: @torbonde: Following Ben's comment, does `R.do.call("mean",R.c(1,2,3,4,5))` do what you want?

Comment: Yes! `R.do_call("mean", R.list(R.c(1,2,3,4,5)))` is what I'm looking for! Thank you so much! @BenBolker, if you make an answer I can accept it.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do.call()` is the function in R for "applying" a function to a list of parameters (a slightly different meaning from applying or mapping a function over a vector or list of values, which is what the `*apply` family does).

The R function for what you want would be

```
do.call("mean",list(c(1,2,3,4,5)))
```

According to the comments (I don't speak F# myself), the F# analogue would be:

```
R.do_call("mean", R.list(R.c(1,2,3,4,5)))
```